# using "should" in past tense

Tags: grammar

I have the follow example sentence:

"I made the decision to work toward these goals. But, I was stuck. Should I choose goal X or goal Y?"

Using 'should' here feels a bit awkward to me, so I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct.

Update: I read that it's possible to use "should" in either past or present tense, but I couldn't find a lot on the internet about it. And so, I wanted to figure out if in this particular instance it was grammatically correct. I thought perhaps it would be more correct to say, "Was I to choose goal X or goal Y?"

Comment: add  your research into 'should' to your question if you please.

Comment: hi @lbf  i've updated it!

Comment: If narrating one's own decision at the time, 'should' would be correct. 'I was in a dilemma: should I choose X or Y ?' This is narrative and describes one's thoughts at the time. But if asking _now_ 'Did I make the correct decision ? it would be 'What should I have chosen ?'

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct.  It does not need any changes.